# How in node.js send response with array of json objects?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, module, pivotaltracker

I want to return array of finished pivotal stories using `pivotal-node` module for node.js.

```
app.get('/delivered_stories', function(request, response) {             
  pivotal.useToken("my_token");
  pivotal.getProjects(function (err, data) {
    var project_ids = data.project.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x.id); });
    console.log('Retrived project ids: '.blue + project_ids);

    project_ids.forEach(function(id) {
      pivotal.getStories(id, { filter: "state:finished" }, function(err, story) {
        response.send(story);
      });
    });
    response.end(); // End the JSON array and response.
  });
});
```

What I am doing wrong? And how to fix it? I get an error:

```
http.js:708
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Whole code: https://gist.github.com/regedarek/30b2f35e92a7f98f4e20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pivotal.getStories()` is **asynchronous**.

Its callback (and therefore `response.send()`) will run some time **after** the rest of your code (including `response.end()`)

In fact, you shouldn't be calling `response.end()` at all; `response.send()` does that for you.

You also cannot call `response.send()` more than once; you need to combine all of the results into a single array and send that.
This is not simple to do; consider using async.js or promises.

Comment: So how I can store ``project_ids`` and pass it to getStories ?

Comment: @regedarek Take a look at the async library for co-ordinating async tasks. https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Oops just saw that the answer mentioned that - still it's worth reiterating ;)